# Remove orphaned module data after uninstall

Tags: installation

I have installed the xmlsitemap module, which is in alpha state. The module has an incomplete uninstall routine. Right now I am getting this error at /admin/config:

> User warning: The following module is missing from the file system:
>   xmlsitemap in drupal_get_filename() (line 240 of
>   core/includes/bootstrap.inc). drupal_get_filename('module',
>   'xmlsitemap') (Line: 263) drupal_get_path('module', 'xmlsitemap')
>   (Line: 134) module_load_include('install', 'xmlsitemap') (Line: 93)
>   module_load_install('xmlsitemap') (Line: 82) drupal_load_updates()
>   (Line: 109) Drupal\system\SystemManager->listRequirements() (Line: 96)
>   Drupal\system\SystemManager->checkRequirements() (Line: 102)
>   Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController->overview('system.admin_config')
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
>   Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
>   (Line: 574)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object)
>   (Line: 124)
>   Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array,
>   Array) (Line: 97)
>   Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
>   call_user_func_array(Object, Array) (Line: 144)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line:
>   64) Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
>   (Line: 57) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1)
>   (Line: 47) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 99)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line:
>   78) Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1)
>   (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1,
>   1) (Line: 50)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1,
>   1) (Line: 23) Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line:
>   656) Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

There are dozens of entries in my database, which are related to this module. Is there any quick way, to remove the module's orphaned data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following database query to remove the module:

#### Drupal 8

```
DELETE FROM key_value WHERE collection='system.schema' AND name='module_name'
```

#### Drupal 7

```
DELETE from system where name = 'old_module1' AND type = 'module'
```

See: [How to fix "The following module is missing from the file system..." warning messages](https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215).

Comment: That worked. The message is not appearing anymore. Apart from that there is orphaned data in the database, which must be cleaned manually.